# Homotopy invariant analogues of localizing invariants

Tags: homotopy-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Given a localizing invariant, $E$, valued in spectra, by following the recipe prescribed in 3.13 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05559, we can define a homotopy-invariant version of $E$ on $H\mathbb{Z}$-linear categories:

$$EH(\mathcal{C}) = \underset{\Delta^{op}}{\text{colim}} \ E(\mathcal{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \text{Perf}_{\mathbb{Z}[\Delta^{\bullet}]}),$$

where $\mathcal{C}$ is an $H\mathbb{Z}$-linear category and $\mathbb{Z}[\Delta^{\bullet}]$ is the simplicial ring of algebraic simplices, as defined in IV.11.3 of Weibel's K-book (https://sites.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html), for example.

**Variation:** One could perform this type of construction with $\mathbb{S}[t] = \Sigma_{+}^{\infty}(\mathbb{N})$, the free $E_{1}$-algebra on a single generator, or $\mathbb{S}\{t\}$, the free $E_{\infty}$-algebra on a single generator.

$KH$ has many nice features not shared by algebraic K-theory. For example, it is a *truncating invariant*, meaning that for $A$ a connective $E_{1}$-ring spectrum, $KH(A) \simeq KH(\pi_{0}A)$ (note, of course, that this is true for K-theory if we look at the negative K-groups). In fact, according to Remark 5.3.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.03340, this result, attributed to Antieau-Gepner-Heller, is true if we use $\mathbb{S}[\Delta^{\bullet}]$ as opposed to $\mathbb{Z}[\Delta^{\bullet}]$.

**Questions**

1. Are there nice structural features that certain homotopy invariant analogues of localizing invariants posses that the original invariants do not? I would be very interested to know some examples aside from $KH$. A back-of-the-envelope calculation suggests homotopy invariant $THH$ will fail to be a truncating invariant.
2. Is there anything that can be said from the motivic point of view? For example, homotopy K-theory is representable by the motivic spectrum $KGL$. I am quite ignorant of the motivic side of things, but it seems like one would have to apply a result of Robalo (Corollary 5.11 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.3645) to obtain something representable. I think this would cut down the collection of localizing invariants which produce anything motivic.
3. What types of comparison results might hold between $E$ and $EH$? For instance, $K$ and $KH$ agree on regular Noetherian rings, and for rings where $\ell$ is invertible, provided we use mod $\ell$ coefficients.
4. How does the Antieau-Gepner-Heller result mentioned above work? Is the proof similar to that of Proposition 3.14 in https://arxiv.org/abs/1808.05559?